# How to extract Campaign level conversions from Facebook marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

In Facebook ad manager, I can see different categories of conversions against each campaign i.e.

```
Website Purchases   9
Website Adds to Cart    724 
Website Registrations Completed 6
Website Checkouts Initiated 24
Website Searches    272
```

I am using graph API to extract this data from Facebook Marketing API([insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v11.0), [attribution](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/attribution/))

Firstly I tried to extract campaign level conversions from [insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v11.0) using

```
act_ad_Account_ID/insights?date_preset=this_month&action_attribution_windows=7d_click&level=campaign&fields=campaign_name,conversions,conversion_values,cost_per_conversion
```

But I could not see the categories i.e. website purchases, adds to cart etc. in the retrieved data.

Then I tried using [attribution](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/attribution/)
with query

```
<Business Unit ID>/conversion_events?fields=name,id,cost_per_1k_impressions
```

as a result, I retrieved these categories associated with business unit ID overall.

```
"data": [
    {
      "name": "Website Searches",
      "id": "11*******772",
      "cost_per_1k_impressions": 11388.238
    },
    {
      "name": "Website Adds to Cart",
      "id": "1121******775",
      "cost_per_1k_impressions": 188.238
    },
    {
      "name": "Website Purchases",
      "id": "11***********7874",
      "cost_per_1k_impressions": 7088.238
    },
    {
      "name": "Website Checkouts Initiated",
      "id": "11212**********",
      "cost_per_1k_impressions": 17088.238
    },
    {
      "name": "Website Subscriptions",
      "id": "1********80141",
      "cost_per_1k_impressions": 1137088.238
    }
```

But these are overall stats, I want to retrieve these stats at campaign level. Where to put down a campaign filter. Just using these API first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answering my own Question here.
We can get conversion data from insights here:

```
act_ad_Account_ID/insights?date_preset=this_month&level=campaign&fields=campaign_name,actions
```

actions return a json, that contain

```
Website Purchases   9
Website Adds to Cart    724 
Website Registrations Completed 6
Website Checkouts Initiated 24
Website Searches    272
```

all these conversions data that we can see on facebook ad manager against each campaign.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was stuck with the same problem.